# "Because $X_i$ is random, the CEF is random"

Tags: conditional-expectation

Define the conditional expectation function (CEF) by $E[Y_i|X_i]$.

In *Mostly Harmless Econometrics*, Angrist and Pischke (2009, p. 30) write:

> Because $X_i$ is random, the CEF is random

I do not understand the above statement.

Say $Y_i$ is real-valued. Then $E[Y_i|X_i]$ gives us, for each specific $X_i$, a real number. In what way is this random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Say $Y_i$ is real-valued.  Then $E[Y_i|X_i]$ gives us, for each specific $X_i$, a real number.  In what way is this random?

Your first two sentences are entirely correct, so think about the implication of this.  This means that the conditional expectation is a *function* mapping each possible outcome of $X_i$ to a real number.  Thus, if we let $\mathscr{X}$ denote the range of possible values of $X_i$ then there is some function $h:\mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_i|X_i) = h(X_i)
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\mathbb{E}(Y_i|X_i=x) = h(x).$$

So, we have established that *the conditional expectation is a function of the conditioning variable*.  In the first of  the two cases shown in the above equations, the conditioning variable is treated as a random variable, so our function of that variable is also random.

Comment: I'd add "as compared to conditioning on $E(Y_i | X_i = x)$".

Comment: @Tim: Edited to show contrast with this case.

Comment: I meant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118578/what-is-the-difference-between-exy-and-exy-y